# applying regex in typescript

Tags: regex, angular, typescript

I am working in angular2
I have a URL link,eg:-www.abcd.com/Computers_Accessories/panache-air-pc/P-coac-20620024815-cat-z.html#newId=P-coac-41130779424?trackId=paym&subTrackId=&infitag=1234

I need to cut the portion #newId=P-coac-41130779424 from the above URL and append it to the end of the URL , so that the new required Url looks like:-
www.abcd.com/Computers_Accessories/panache-air-pc/P-coac-20620024815-cat-z.html?trackId=paym&subTrackId=&infitag=1234#newId=P-coac-41130779424
is there any method to apply Regex in typescript to get this result, or else any other proper method to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex

```
(.*)(#newId=.*)(?=\?)(.*)
```

and replace it with (1st group)(3rd group)(2nd group)

check out the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/q5TY8W/1)

```js
let str = 'www.abcd.com/Computers_Accessories/panache-air-pc/P-coac-20620024815-cat-z.html#newId=P-coac-41130779424?trackId=paym&subTrackId=&infitag=1234';

str = str.replace(/(.*)(#newId=.*)(?=\?)(.*)/g, "$1$3$2");

console.log(str);
```

Comment: what if i need to split it to something like that look link downstairs how is it done in typescript (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076594/split-java-log-line-with-regex)