# split java log line with regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to split a log line which looks like this:

```
15:10:10,408 INFO <NioProcessor-11> Raw Message: 8=FIXT.1.1|9=317|35=D|49=verifix|
```

into something like this:

```
15:10:10 
408
INFO
NioProcessor-11
FIXT.1.1
317
D
verifix
```

each information in split.

I have tried to split it with the split function with only

`mystring.split((,)| \\\|)` which splits my code to something like that:

```
15:10:10
408 INFO <NioProcessor-11> Raw Message: 8=FIXT.1.1
9=317
35=D
49=verifix
```

Then I took the second split `408 INFO <NioProcessor-11> Raw Message: 8=FIXT.1.1`

and do a substring. It worked, but not perfectly because sometimes the second split is longer or shorter and it doesn't look to be a good solution.

I would like to know if it's possible to split that string with regex expressions actually. I'm new to regex and I didn't find a way to write an expression that handles my objective.

Comment: it would be helpful if you can mention few more sample of log lines in your logfiles. Currently, it only mentioned a single pattern of logs.

Comment: How about a single split `[, <>]|(?: Raw Message: )?\|?\d+=|\|`

Comment: Try splitting on [`(?:> [^:]+: |\d+=|[ ,|<>])+`](https://regex101.com/r/dnuO7P/1)

Comment: yes ctwheels it works tahnk you

Answer (score 1):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/dnuO7P/1)

```
(?:> [^:]+: |\d+=|[ ,|<>])+
```

- `(?:)+` Match any of the following options one or more times

  - `> [^:]+:` Matches `>` , then one or more of any character except `:`, then `:`
  - `\d+=` Match one or more digits, then `=`
  - `[ ,|<>]` Match any character in the set

Result:

```
15:10:10
408
INFO
NioProcessor-11
FIXT.1.1
317
D
verifix
```

Answer (score 0):

if you search for a generic solution this could be helpful

```
    final String first = "15:10:10,408 INFO <NioProcessor-11> Raw Message: 8=FIXT.1.1|9=317|35=D|49=verifix|";
    final String second = "408 INFO <NioProcessor-11> Raw Message: 8=FIXT.1.1";

    String pattern = "[,| ]";
    Arrays.stream(first.split(pattern)).forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    Arrays.stream(second.split(pattern)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

but if you want to get the specified elements, use groups  and a specific pattern.

Comment: thank you for asking so your pattern split whether he find a( ',' space or pipe) what if i want to split these  8=FIXT.1.1|9=317 without those 8= & 9=  =to=> FIXT.1.1 and 317 .. is there a  way ?

Comment: there are a lot of tools around regex search for "regex coach" or "regex tester" and use the one you like most. even for IDE (Eclipse for example) there are plugins

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_HTKPvXjEc&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9g6m_6Sld9Q4jzqdqHd2HiD&index=4 check this course

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: [`(?:> Raw Message: |\|)?(?:\d+=|[ ,<|]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/0kfb2D/2)

Details:

- `(?:> Raw Message: |\|)?` Non-capturing group `(?:)` match `> Raw Message:` **or** `|` pipe `\|` if they exist `?`
- `(?:\d+=|[ ,<|]+)` Non-capturing group `(?:)` match digit one or unlimited times `\d+` **or** `|` match a single character present in the list `[ ,<|]+`  one or unlimited times `+`

**Java code**:

```
String test = "15:10:10,408 INFO <NioProcessor-11> Raw Message: 8=FIXT.1.1|9=317|35=D|49=verifix|";
String[] data =test.split("(?:> Raw Message: |\\|)?(?:\\d+=|[ ,<|]+)");
for(String r : data) {
    System.out.println(r);
}
```

Output:

```
15:10:10
408
INFO
NioProcessor-11
FIXT.1.1
317
D
verifix
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/dI9hKN)

Comment: @alaaeddine zammel Practice a lot!

Comment: any links or sources ?

Comment: @alaaeddine Just google. You can search right here with tag 'regex' and find a lot of simple examples that you can solve by your self. Use [regex101](https://regex101.com) as a practice tool.

Comment: thank you sorry can't upvote your response ~~cause im  new to stack i will google :)

Comment: @alaaeddine zammel  No problem. Glad I could help. See [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) section of SO.

Answer (score 0):

@alaaeddine zammel thats more specific

```
    final String input = "8=FIXT.1.1|9=317";
    final String groupPattern = "\\d=([A-Z\\.\\d]*)\\|\\d=([A-Z\\.\\d]*)";
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(groupPattern);
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
    }
```